# Getting a parameter value without a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, slim-lang

I have the following slim code. I am not using a model like how `form_for` requires it. I am only directing it towards a controller.

```
= form_tag '/mycontroller' do
    div.field
      = check_box_tag 'Notify'
      = label_tag 'Notify'
    div.actions
      = submit_tag 'Save'
```

How is the value being passed? Do I need strong parameters since I am using Rails 4? How do I access the checkbox value in `mycontroller` using this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value will be passed as a key in the "root" of the params hash. You should ba able to access it with `params['Notify']` (if I'm wrong, just inspect params, it should be obvious which it is). You do not need to use strong parameters unless you are doing mass assignment with the values.

Answer (score 0):

in Controller

```
class MyController
  def create
    @notify = params[:Notify]
  end
end
```

in View

```
= form_tag '/mycontroller' do
  div.field
    = check_box_tag 'Notify', true, @notify
    = label_tag 'Notify'
  div.actions
    = submit_tag 'Save'
```